# How do I add a Run command into my python code?

Tags: python

```
firstnumber=int(input('Firstnumber'))
secondnumber=int(input('Secondnumber'))
addorsubtract=input('Add or subtact?')
add=(firstnumber+secondnumber)
minus=(firstnumber-secondnumber)
if addorsubtract==("+"):
    print (add)
if addorsubtract==("-"):
    print (minus)
```

This is my simple code for my calculator python code, how do Make it so I can clear the answer printed and run the code again without having to tab out and run it again?

Comment: Make a loop? Make a function? Start in the python tutorials, it's all there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. I've tested it.

```
def calc():
    firstnumber=int(input('Firstnumber'))
    secondnumber=int(input('Secondnumber'))
    addorsubtract=input('Add or subtact?')
    add=(firstnumber+secondnumber)
    minus=(firstnumber-secondnumber)
    if addorsubtract==("+"):
        print (add)
    if addorsubtract==("-"):
        print (minus)

while True:
    c = input("continue?(Y/N)")
    if c == 'Y' or c == 'y':
        calc()
    else:
        break
```

Comment: This seems like it should work but for some reason on my python program the "=" next to continue is apparently an invalid syntax               I'm Using python 3.3.2 If that helps

Comment: @ laike9mThanks for helping me with this, this time it worked.